# Excel dynamic YTD vs PYTD, based on actuals of this year

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dynamic, cell, calculation

I have full year 2023 sales by months and I have Jan-Feb 2024 actual sales by months by categories
I would like to have YTD vs PYTD difference % calculated automatically as I input actuals of 2024

[image: example]

For example, next time I enter March 2024 (green range), YTD vs PYTD % difference (yellow cell) should be calculated based on Jan-March 2024 vs Jan-March 2023

I need this to be calculated in one yellow column

I tried

```
IF(B35>0;SUM($B35:B35)/SUM($B17:B17)-1;0)
```

but the problem is I need this dynamic in one column, not 12 columns

I would appreciate any help here

Comment: I tried IF(B35>0;SUM($B35:B35)/SUM($B17:B17)-1;0) but the problem is I need this dynamic in one column, not 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assuming there is no `Excel Constraints` and while writing this formula if the `Beta` Channel is enabled then one could use the following formula:*

[image]

---

```
=BYROW(IF(B8:M10<>"",B8:M10,0),SUM)/BYROW(IF(B8:M10<>"",B2:M4,0),SUM)-1
```

---

or, Using `MMULT()`

```
=MMULT(IF(B8:M10<>"",B8:M10,0),SEQUENCE(12)^0)/
 MMULT(IF(B8:M10<>"",B2:M4,0),SEQUENCE(12)^0)-1
```

Comment: Not sure why but it shows #NAME?"

Comment: @BT please read the opening statement of my answer, hope it will help you to understand. One it could be you are not a `MS365` user, second even if you are using `MS365` you have not enabled the `Beta` version! Alternative approach updated

Comment: MMULT worked ! Thank you!

Comment: @BT glad to know `MMULT()` worked!